# How do you add positional parameters?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a simple bash script that takes two parameters and sums them.  How can I fix this?

```
#!/bin/bash
add = $(($1+$2))
echo Addition       : $add

# sample 7 15
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the 'space' before and after the '='.

```
                    add = $(($1+$2))

                          to

                    add=$(($1+$2))
```

So your complete pgm will be like this

```
#!/bin/bash
add=$(($1+$2))
echo Addition       : $add

# sample 7 15
```

Comment: Also change `echo Addition'_______': $add` if you'd like to preserve the spaces before `:`. (Replace underscores with spaces).

Answer (score 4):

As aneeshep rightly pointed out, your problem is the spaces around the `=` sign. There should be no spaces around the equal sign when performing variable assignment.

```
#!/bin/bash
TOTAL=$(($1 + $2))
echo "Addition       : $TOTAL"
```

or simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Addition       : $(($1 + $2))"
```

---

As an aside, other alternatives to your script include using the [`let`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#LETREF) bash builtin command which is great for simple arithmetic operations:

```
#!/bin/bash
let "TOTAL = $1 + $2"
echo "Addition       : $TOTAL"
```

Or the [c-style variable manipulation within double parentheses](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
(( TOTAL = $1 + $2 ))
echo "Addition       : $TOTAL"
```